# Combine two columns, ignore empty cells and add a separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I need to combine column `1` and `2` in `3` with separator `,` but ignore empty cells.
So I have this dataframe:

```
         1     2
0  A, B, B     D
1           C, D
2  B, B, C  D, A
```

And need to create column `3` (desired output):

```
         1     2              3
0  A, B, B     D     A, B, B, D
1           C, D           C, D
2  B, B, C  D, A  B, B, C, D, A
```

So as you see here, empty sell was ignored and `,` separate elements between in df["3"] (`B, B, C, D, A`).

I try to do this with simple concatenation, but didn't succeed.

If I simple concatenate `df["1"] + df["2"]` I will get that the last element of first column combine with first element of last column (`BD`, `CD`):

```
         1     2            3
0  A, B, B     D     A, B, BD
1           C, D         C, D
2  B, B, C  D, A  B, B, CD, A
```

If add ", " (`df["1"] + ", " + df["2"]`):

```
         1     2              3
0  A, B, B     D     A, B, B, D
1           C, D         , C, D
2  B, B, C  D, A  B, B, C, D, A
```

You will see that each empty cell replace with ", " and added to df["3"] (example = `, C, D`, but I need `C, D`).

Code for reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"1":["A, B, B","","B, B, C"], "2":["D","C, D","D, A"]})
print(df)
```

Comment: You just have to strip it off: `(df["1"] + ", " + df["2"]).str.lstrip(', ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for possible removing `,` from both sides:

```
(df["1"] + ", " + df["2"]).str.strip(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

how about multiple columns with empty cells in the middle?

```
A|B|C|D|E|F
1| |3| |5|6
```

This should produce:

```
A|B|C|D|E|F|Full
1| |3| |5|6|1$3$5$6
```